# sphere cast outputting only the center of the game object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, physics

i'm trying to make a aimbot that detects with the sphere cast if it's hitting something i a bigger radius and if the aimbot is on then it shoots the bullet there, but it keeps outputting the middle of the hit gameobject
spherecast() it's called in update
aim gameobject it's a representation of the position where the bullet should get if the aim is on
code:

```
public void spherecast()
    {
        origin = gunTip.transform.position;
        direction = guntip.transform.forward;
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.SphereCast(origin,sphereradus, direction,out hit,maxDistance,whatIsenemy))
    {
        Debug.Log("I hit enemy");
        Debug.Log("position" + hit.transform.position);
        aim.transform.position = hit.transform.position;
        currentHitDistance = hit.distance;
    }
    else
    {
        currentHitDistance = maxDistance;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Physics.SphereCast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.SphereCast.html) outputs nothing like that at all.

It is you using `hit.transform.position` which of course is the general pivot point of the hit object.

`SphereCast` provides you with a [`RaycastHit`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit.html) with a lot of additional information like in particular the [`RaycastHit.point`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit-point.html) you are looking for!

```
public void spherecast()
{
    origin = gunTip.transform.position;
    direction = guntip.transform.forward;

    if (Physics.SphereCast(origin, sphereradus, direction,out var hit, maxDistance, whatIsenemy))
    {
        // By passing in the hit object you can click on the log in the console 
        // and it will highlight the according object in your scene ;)
        Debug.Log($"I hit enemy \"{hit.gameObject}\"", hit.gameObject);

        Debug.Log($"hit position: {hit.point}", this);
        aim.transform.position = hit.point;
        currentHitDistance = hit.distance;
    }
    else
    {
        currentHitDistance = maxDistance;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

U want [hit.Point](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit-point.html) to get the position where the sphere touched the collider it hit.
[Here are docs on raycasthit object](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit.html)